# Moodle web service Rest api,send encrypted email

Tags: php, ssl, moodle, moodle-api

I'm trying to login a user with user key authentication and I'm sending email address to this plugin in order to generate an authorized URL. I also need to send the email address encrypted and I'm decrypting the email address in moodle plugin and validating the email. When I try this at my local server it's working fine but when I install the plugin to the live it's giving me this error.

```
"user => Invalid parameter value detected: email => Invalid parameter value detected: Invalid external api parameter: the value is \"hl9FC3SKmCDBZ0 hNS4FKg70GbpRXc/eRXt9fQ hDs4=\", the server was expecting \"email\" type"
```

Is this default moodle validations? If so can I override them inside my function?

Answer (score 2):

Finally  i found a solution, this might not be the best way but it worked.

**steps**

1. Add '@abc.com' to end of the encrypted email string
2. Url encode the whole string
3. Send to the moodle and validation is passed:)

You can URL decode the email inside the moodle.